# RAW image viewer with rating capability?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing, photo-management

An image viewer that

1. Can display (the embedded JPG inside) RAW files.
2. Supports rating images *and* can write the ratings into the files.
3. Does not need to "import" the images.

I don't know any. Shotwell requires images to be imported and Geeqie cannot write the ratings into the file (as far as I can tell). Gthumb cannot display the preview JPG in a RAW file.

Answer (score 4):

1. Geeqie can handle RAW files correctly.  If you want to see thumbnails in nautilus you can use ufraw and create a thumb-nailer.  It uses the raw embedded image and is the faster thumb-nailer I've seen. To do this, first install ufraw-batch. Then create a text file called /usr/share/thumbnailers/raw.thumbnailer and copy this:

   ```
   [Thumbnailer Entry]
   TryExec=ufraw-batch
   Exec=ufraw-batch --silent --size %s --out-type=png --noexif --output=%o --overwrite --embedded-image %i
   MimeType=image/x-adobe-dng;image/x-canon-cr2;image/x-canon-crw;image/x-dcraw;image/x-fuji-raf;image/x-kodak-dcr;image/x-kodak-k25;image/x-kodak-kdc;image/x-minolta-mrw;image/x-nikon-nef;image/x-olympus-orf;image/x-panasonic-raw;image/x-pentax-pef;image/x-sigma-x3f;image/x-sony-arw;image/x-sony-sr2;image/x-sony-srf;
   ```
2. Probably is not exactly what you are looking for, but I use Geeqie and use the keywords to rate them (you can add new keywords if needed).
   To select the images you right-clik on the keyword and connect the keyword to a mark.

   And you can also batch copy or move the files. Select the images, right-click on the keyword and connect to a mark, the select the mark and on the icon panel now you only see the selected images.  Then you can click on an icon and then Ctrl-A to select all images, righ-click and press copy.
3. Geeqie doesn't need to import images.

Comment: Where does Geeqie store the tags and can it do batch operations (such as copying) based on tags?

Comment: The keyword tags are stored in ~/.local/share/geeqie/metadata (you can see the path in edit-->preferences-->thumbnail manteinance

Comment: @Reza be sure to dl and compile the latest geekie version from the site http://geeqie.org/